# Is there a single word for a "non-empty" string?

Tags: terminology, strings

Take a simple example:

```
string1 = ""
string2 = "foo"
```

`string1` is empty or null, which is clear.

But what about `string2`? I wouldn't call it "full". "Non-empty" or "non-null" works, but is there not a single word that unambiguously captures the meaning of "not empty" in the context of a string?

Comment: In the context of mathematics, it would probably be called "nontrivial." I don't know of any term in CS.

Comment: If the downvoter can suggest any way to improve this question, that would be appreciated!

Comment: @DavidPement there is nothing trivial about null. It is an information destroying hole in the universe of your model. Treat it lightly at your peril.

Comment: There are couple of value categories that you may want to make a distinction between (or, in other situations, group them under the same umbrella): null, "" (empty), "    " (nonempty whitespace), "foo" (non-null non-whitespace). I'm not sure there's a universally accepted single-word term that would be unanbiguous. If you're trying to communicate things in code, you could, say, name a function sometheing like `IsNotWhitespaceOrNull(str)`, etc.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović, well, some enterprising influencer could make `INWON` the term to fill this lexical gap ...

Comment: Part of the community here downvotes every "name that thing" question categorically (which would be ok for me if they would leave a comment on it, which they usually don't). When you read [this old meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology) from 2014, there was IMHO not a real consensus of a question like this one should be accepted. The community today is even more picky about it. ...

Comment: .. said that, I think "name-that-thing" questions are way more better received when they ask about something interesting. I - personally - don't see the concept of an empty string as something particular interesting. I cannot remember lacking a better name for it.

Comment: You can call it “nonempty” without hyphen. On the other hand, that’s a word that my spelling checker doesn’t like.

Comment: @Doc I do most of my work with Swift / Objective C where I would indeed use nil for “nothing” and “” for a normal string of length 0. Unfortunately I have to work with some C++ interfaces that use “” to mean “nothing”.

Comment: @Filip: IsNonWhiteSpace. Nil, “” and “ “ are all without any non-whitespace characters.

Comment: What is the context (reasoning) that necessitates a single-word terminology for non-empty strings? Please explain.

Comment: @gnasher729 - the problem with that is that, while technically correct, you're writing for human readers, and that's not how humans normally talk (even if they are mathematicians :) ). Furthermore, if the reader has no context about how precise, and how consistently precise, the language used for naming is, it doesn't make the name less ambiguous. So redundancy in the name is not necessarily a bad thing - it's a bit of a judgement call, depending on how well you know your "readership".

Comment: @rwong - I'm writing code that frequently distinguishes between empty and non-empty strings - in my notes it's personally a bit annoying to not have an obvious conciser way to refer to non-empty strings.

Comment: An empty string is still a string! If you are looking for a string with at least one character, that is a non-zero-length string.

Comment: In some languages (German for instance) "non-empty" _would_ be a single word.

Answer (score 10):

A variable that is assigned a value is said to be "populated."

That's about as close as you're going to get, unfortunately.  A populated string variable (or a string of non-zero length) is just not interesting enough in and of itself to ascribe a single-word term.

Comment: Huh, I suspected this would be the case, but thanks. Your display pic is beautiful, by the way ;-)

Answer (score 1):

At least one of the languages I use, chose the pragmatic solution: `nonempty`. Bam. One word.

Answer (score 0):

As well as endorsing Robert Harvey's word "populated", I'd like to suggest the words `replete` or even `impleted` as the opposite of empty.

Although these words are more or less a synonym of "full", and perhaps even over-fullness and excess, in this context they're far more unusual words than "full" with fewer connotations of wholeness or limited capacity, and a stronger connotation of there being a complement of one or more individual items present (which is the same connotation that "populated" carries).

For example, you can use "full" like "he ate a full cake", which means the entirety of a single cake, not multiple cakes. Or "the dungeon was full" strongly suggests that it has reached its capacity, not that it is merely populated. These are connotations which make it unsuitable to talk of a "full string", which can be as little as one character or an indefinite number of characters.

They're also snappy words and not needlessly long to write or pronounce.

I seem to remember a similar question arising recently, and should I myself encounter a need to describe something (a container, array, string, etc.) that is "nonempty", I think "replete" may well be the word I turn to.

Correspondingly, I could well envisage myself generically describing a string that consists only either of a null, an empty string, or whitespace, as "nonreplete".